# Where is my Rails log file after deployed to VPS using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps

I have deploy my Rails app to a VPS (Nginx + Unicorn + Postgres) using Capistrano 3, but I got an error page "we're sorry, but something went wrong." And I can't find my Rails log file, I uncommented this line in the deploy.rb, and still cannot find it.

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

There are log files in my current/log directory and shared/log/, but they don't get updated when I refresh my error page.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `stderr_path "#{root}/shared/log/unicorn.log"` and
`stdout_path "#{root}/shared/log/unicorn.log"` in your unicorn.rb file?

Comment: Yes, root = "/var/www/projectx/current" stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

Comment: and `tail -n 100 /var/www/projectx/current/log/unicorn.log` returns nothing?

Comment: There is no unicorn.log file in my current/log directory. only (development.log     newrelic_agent.log  staging.log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

1. `touch /var/www/projectx/shared/log/unicorn.log`
2. Update your unicorn.rb file with:

   ```
   stderr_path "#{root}/shared/log/unicorn.log"
   stdout_path "#{root}/shared/log/unicorn.log"
   ```
3. Restart your unicorn workers and master process.

Reason: your log file will be reset each time you will update your repo.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I restart unicorn workers and master process? Sorry I am new to this :(

Comment: Which tutorial did you use to set this up? There are a few different ways.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5

Comment: When I type  unicorn_rails -c /var/www/projectx/current/config/unicorn.rb -D, I get master failed to start, check stderr log for details, where can I find the stderr log then?

Comment: Right, it says  Address already in use :), but still where do I find my Rails Application log..

Comment: Could this be why?  to unix:/tmp/unicorn.projectx.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 125.238.28.36, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.projectx.sock:/", host: "128.199.204.94"

Comment: My unicorn.rb file has listen "/tmp/unicorn.projectx.sock" and nginx default.conf has upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/tmp/unicorn.projectx.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

Comment: "Address already in use" is because probably unicorn_rails is already running. Personally I don't like digitalocean's tutorial because there is no way to restart unicorn without stopping nginx. So you can try `sudo service nginx restart`, or `sudo service unicorn_rails stop` and then try to start it. If it does not help - try following another tutorial.